# Trying to Parse /etc/passwd Using Java 8 with Streams

Tags: java, unix, stream, java-stream

Am trying to parse the /etc/passwd file on a macOS Mojave 10.14.3 operating system using Java 1.8's stream feature.

The first five lines inside my /etc/passwd file are as follows:

```
nobody:*:-2:-2:Unprivileged User:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
root:*:0:0:System Administrator:/var/root:/bin/sh
daemon:*:1:1:System Services:/var/root:/usr/bin/false
_uucp:*:4:4:Unix to Unix Copy 
Protocol:/var/spool/uucp:/usr/sbin/uucico
_taskgated:*:13:13:Task Gate Daemon:/var/empty:/usr/bin/false
```

Here's my implementation:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class User {

    String name;
    Integer uid;
    Integer gid;
    String comment;
    String home;
    String shell;

    public User(String filePath) {
        String[] items = filePath.split(":");

        if (items.length != 7) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Need 7 items from file and there's only: " + items.length);
        }

        this.name = items[0];
        this.uid = Integer.parseInt(items[2]);
        this.gid = Integer.parseInt(items[3]);
        this.comment = items[4];
        this.home = items[5];
        this.shell = items[6];
    }

    // Getters and Setters omitted for brevity.


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Read the file
        try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get("/etc/passwd")))
        {
            ArrayList<User> users = stream.map(User::new).filter(u -> !u.shell.equals("/bin/false"))
                                                         .filter(u -> !u.shell.equals("/usr/sbin/nologin"))
                                                         .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
            for (User user : users) {
                System.out.println("User: " + user.name);
            }
        } 

        catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

IllegalArgumentException:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Need 7 items from file and there's only: 1
    at com.sample.model.User.<init>(User.java:23)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.sample.model.User.main(User.java:88)
```

Question(s):

1. What am I possibly doing wrong?
2. Is there a different way to do this instead of using Java 1.8's Streams  feature? It seems like Streams are harder to debug...

Comment: *"It seems like Streams are harder to debug..."* Not at all, for this case at least. Put a breakpoint on the `throw` statement and check the `filePath` value to see how that value differs from your expectation. Alternatively, add the value of `filePath` to the exception text. As soon as you see the value of `filePath`, it'll be obvious why it fails.

Comment: *BTW:* `filePath` is a really bad name for that parameter. `line` might be better.

Comment: @Andreas - Thanks for the suggestion, I changed it to line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to account for lines that are comments / begin with '#'.

So:

```
ArrayList<User> users = stream.filter(s -> s.charAt(0) != '#')
                              .map(User::new)
                              .filter(u -> !u.shell.equals("/bin/false"))
                              .filter(u -> !u.shell.equals("/usr/sbin/nologin"))
                              .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

On your point re: debugging - yup - the tooling isn't great (yet). You could probably have caught this by inspecting the `filePath` passed to the User constructor and observing it was a comment.